# How can I use two lists to create a Table (Columns and Rows)

Tags: r

I want to write a script in R that allows me to import MSG files and store the information in a table. The fields may vary by course, so the column names are defined based on the first MSG file being imported.

The import and extraction are already working (special thanks to the user "January")

What does not work is the filling in the table, which consists of two steps. Add column names and fill in rows.

I've tried using unlist to prepare the contents of the lists so that I can add them as colums and rows to a table.

```
Anmeldung <- gsub("^\\s+", "", Anmeldung) # remove spaces at the beginning and end
Anmeldung <- gsub("\\s+$", "", Anmeldung)
words <- strsplit(Anmeldung, " *[\n\r]+ *")[[1]]




fields <- as.list(words[seq(1, length(words), 2)])
information <- as.list(words[seq(2, length(words), 2)])



resTab1 = data.frame(t(unlist(fields)))
resTab2 = data.frame(t(unlist(information)))

colnames(resTab2) = c(resTab1)
variable.names(resTab2)
```

When I am trying to create the Table,this error appears:

```
colnames(resTab2) = c(resTab1)
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [22] must be the same length as the vector [21]
```

This is what the Dataframes Fields and Information look like:

**Fields**

```
    > fields
[[1]]
[1] "Anrede"

[[2]]
[1] "Vorname"

[[3]]
[1] "Name"

[[4]]
[1] "Email (fÃ¼r Kontaktaufnahme)"

[[5]]
[1] "Telefon/Mobile (geschÃ¤ftlich)"

[[6]]
[1] "Telefon/Mobile (privat)"

[[7]]
[1] "Strasse/Nr."
```

**Information:**

```
    > information
[[1]]
[1] "Herr"

[[2]]
[1] "James"

[[3]]
[1] "Bond"

[[4]]
[1] "james.bond@email.com"

[[5]]
[1] "007 000 77 07"

[[6]]
[1] "007 000 77 07"

[[7]]
[1] "Lampenstrasse 8"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're trying to give names to resTab2 that is shorter than your resTab1

ex:

```
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c("a","b","c")
names(x) <- y

#Error in names(x) <- y : 
#'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

*EDIT:*

use `unlist` to flatten the list

```
information <- unlist(information)
fields <- unlist(fields) 

names(information) <- fields
information

#OUTPUT

                        #Anrede      'Herr'
                       #Vorname      'James'
                          #Name      'Bond'
  #Email (fÃ¼r Kontaktaufnahme)      'james.bond@email.com'
#Telefon/Mobile (geschÃ¤ftlich)      '007 000 77 07'
       #Telefon/Mobile (privat)      '007 000 77 07'
                   #Strasse/Nr.      'Lampenstrasse 8'
```

Comment: to test it I have created a df with 22 entries. but it seems to be a dimension problem.

'Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = list(X1 = 1L, X2 = 1L, X3 = 1L,  : 
  Versuch die 'colnames' für ein Objekt mit weniger als zwei Dimensionen zu setzen'

...For clarification, I have added the contents of the DF Fields and Information in the post

Comment: @crillez, check the edit..if it does not solve the problem provide the sample `dput(data)` i will have a look.